# layout_gravity="bottom" doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gravity

Hello stackoverflow community!
I'm newbie both in programming and on this site, but let's get to the point.
I wrote an app:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity"
        android:padding="24dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="56sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:onClick="plus3a"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:onClick="plus2a"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:onClick="plus1a"
            android:text="Free throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity"
        android:padding="24dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team B"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="56sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:onClick="plus3b"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:onClick="plus2b"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:onClick="plus1b"
            android:text="Free throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="scoreReset"
        android:text="reset" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a problem with positioning a button at the end.
I want it to be at the bottom of a screen and centered horizontally.
I know I could use relative layout but I decided to check if I can do this using linear layout. And seems that I can't... "bottom" attribute is being ignored.

Comment: try it whit linear layout above of button

Comment: "bottom" doesn't work on vertical orientated LinearLayout

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875284/using-layout-gravity-bottom-to-place-at-bottom-of-linearlayout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do one change.

Remove this line from the last button

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

And add this line in the Linear layout which is containing your last button

```
android:gravity="bottom|center"
```

Here is the output:

[image]

[Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965883/what-is-exact-difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity) to get a clear idea about gravity and layout_gravity. It'll surely help you in your upcoming designs.

Comment: android:gravity="bottom|center" not android:layout_gravity

Comment: Ahh, yes, sorry. I'm blind. Now it's working perfectly ^^

Comment: like i said in my aswer :) (glad to hear)

Comment: You should upvote on @Anto's answer too as well as all other answers which you find helpful. It encourages one to help others more :) Mido

Answer (score 1):

You can add this View before last button:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Add this -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="scoreReset"
        android:text="reset" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I also removed the bottom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try encapsulating the main layout in one LinearLayout with layout_weight = 1, layout_width = "match_parent", layout_height = "match_parent"and button at bottom in another LinearLayout with layout_width="match_parent" and gravity set to bottom|center_horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="bottom|center">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:onClick="scoreReset"
    android:text="reset"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't android:layout_alignParentBottom apply only to relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

use gravity="bottom" instead of layout_gravity it should help.

Comment: It moves text in the button, not the button itself.