# Button breaks LinearLayout layout_gravity top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I may be being an idiot, but it seems like adding a `Button` to a horizontal `LinearLayout` breaks `layout_gravity="top"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:background="#f00" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This looks like this (in the layout editor):

[image: screenshot]

Note that the text view is in the *centre*, not the top! If *all I do is remove the `<button>`, then it looks like this:

[image: working screenshot]

See, now it is at the top like it should be. A workaround I will use is to have `layout_gravity="start"` which does result in the correct behaviour:

[image]

But anyway, what's going on? Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575409/linearlayout-layout-gravity-bottom-not-working-on-horizontal-linearlayout). That might actually be the same problem; I'm not sure. No real answers there anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, I found the answer! You have to set `android:baselineAligned="false"`. Never heard of that before, and kind of annoying that it is on by default!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

...
```