# how to display widget at bottom of screen android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to display widget button at bottom of screen.

I want to display **Send button** at the bottom of the screen.

Attaching the screenshot :

[image]

The following the is the layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/to"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/subject"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/message"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:text="@string/send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Check the button (Send) above i want to display this button at bottom of the screen. what should i do. I have used android:layout_gravity=0.0 for the button widget, but not works.

Comment: You should use a `RelativeLayout` instead of the `LinearLayout` you are using now, and there you can set `android:alignParentBottom="true"`.

Comment: Cant we do that in Linear Layout.

Comment: @vermaraj No..you need to use RelativeLayout for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align views at the bottom of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Comment: Dude this is literelly the **first** thing you find in **any** tutorial about Android, do the minimal research before posting!

Comment: @avalancha I did this but i want to do this with Linear Layout. Because there may be various changes in the layout xml. this is just a sample. That's why i tried to do it in Linear layout.

Comment: @vermaraj if you know we can do this in linear layout then i am curious to know how

Comment: Well that's not really an excuse now is it? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779688/put-buttons-at-bottom-of-screen-with-linearlayout), [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575409/linearlayout-layout-gravity-bottom-not-working-on-horizontal-linearlayout)... Can all be found on the **1st page** [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=linearlayout+align+bottom)

Comment: @vermaraj,is my solution not solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Relative Layout instead of LinearLayout easily:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="to"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_below="@id/to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="subject"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_below="@id/sub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="message"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="send"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In LinearLayout, you won't be able to do this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Of course you're [able to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575409/linearlayout-layout-gravity-bottom-not-working-on-horizontal-linearlayout), if you're answering a duplicate question please do the reasearch

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/message"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Relative Layout** For you Layout file

and Change

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:text="@string/send"/>
```

Via

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/send"/>
```