# Align Button to Bottom using LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Trying to align button at Bottom using LinearLayout, but getting just below TextView.

To set button at bottom, I am using `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` but still not done

**LinearLayout xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bottom" />

        </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575409/linearlayout-layout-gravity-bottom-not-working-on-horizontal-linearlayout

Comment: Better to use RelativeLayout

Comment: @MD I agree but please check above link

Comment: Use the Relative Layout to solve your issue

Comment: @Oreo give your design what exactly you want

Comment: see the link @IntelliJ Amiya gave above. Its the best solution. Visit the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:baselineAligned for more details

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change second linear layout to

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

This will put the button at the bottom and this layout will take the rest of the space

Answer (score 4):

Yoy have to use like this....

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bottom" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Agree for `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: `layout_alignParentBottom` gave an error on android studio, so I just used `gravity="bottom"` on the `RelativeLayout` and that worked

Answer (score 2):

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bottom" />

        </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not use the suggested answer as I had multiples of 3 vertical ones (each with specific weights) inside a horizontal one. So, ended up using margin top for specific button/widget instead. Working fine so far.

Did not want to change to RelativeLayout as that meant many changes in this scenario.

[image: Example Layout]